# Jquery - Resonse.statusText is undefined even though it shows up in the browser tools

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, backbone.js

In my Action Methods I return:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
     return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500, "This is an error!");
}
```

In my backbone.js fetch I am using this:

```
 error: function(response, status, error) {
               alert(response.statusText);
 }
```

The broswer tools are showing my message under Status but the alertbox is saying undefined.
[image]

I saw this method in this thread -> [Custom Error message with HTTPStatusCodeResult & jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348111/custom-error-message-with-httpstatuscoderesult-jquery)

Any idea why it's not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the arguments of the `error` callback:

```
(model, response, options)
```

So basically you're trying to get `model.statusText` which is of course undefined. The `response` corresponds to the 2nd argument, so try `response.statusText` (in your case, `status.statusText` ~~).

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something simple.