# HttpStatusCodeResult(401) returns "302 Found"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http-status-codes, asp.net-mvc-5

Using ASP.NET MVC 5, I would like to return appropriate HTTP status code for different scenarios (401 for user is not authenticated, 403 when user has no right for some resource, etc.), than handle them in jQuery.

But the problem is, when I try to return 401, it always returns "302: Found". What is the trick for a custom status code, and why this doesn't work?

```
public ActionResult My()
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(401, "User is not authenticated."); 
            // Returns "302: Found"
    }

   // ... other code ...
}
```

**EDIT 1: Interesting bit:**

If I replace the 401 with a 404 like this:

```
return new HttpNotFoundResult("User is not authenticated.");
```

Then it indeed gives a 404 and jQuery can catch the problem. However it's not an elegant solution as the error code is different.

**EDIT 2:** 302 is not good for me, as the result would be used in `jQuery.get().fail()`, but 302 won't triger `fail()`

Comment: are you using forms authentication?

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348111/custom-error-message-with-httpstatuscoderesult-jquery

Comment: mrtig: I've seen this before, but doesn't help as it says it's solved by using IIS express. I use IIS express, still I have the problem.

Comment: Daniel A. White: I'm using the default built-in auth in the ASP.NET MVC5 template called "Individual User Accounts"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Lol this is an awesome problem

The way auth works in MVC is that when you aren't logged in and try to access a secure page it throws a 401 exception. MVC then catches this exception and redirects the user to the login page (which is the 302 you are seeing)

I suppose there's a few things you can do to fix it:

- Ignore it, its probably the behaviour you want anyway
- Disable login page redirection (phil haack has a good article on this here: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx)

**EDIT**

As per your comments, the following code will turn all redirects into 401s when requested via ajax. This is one approach for avoiding the issue listed

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication {
    protected void Application_EndRequest() {
        var context = new HttpContextWrapper(Context);
        // If we're an ajax request, and doing a 302, then we actually need to do a 401
        if (Context.Response.StatusCode == 302 && context.Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
            Context.Response.Clear();
            Context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The redirect won't happen, as the controller's method is called via AJAX, that's why I need something other than 302, so `jQuery.get` could recognize it.

Comment: @user2270404 take a look at phil haacks code around this. He creates an HTTP module to sort this issue out and return a 401 anyway (for exactly the ajax case) Its a bit messsy but it should sort out your problem. According to the article there is also a better way to get around this if you are using .NET 4.5 stuff

Comment: I've checked the article, it's a bit messy. I'm using .NET 4.5.1 and checked the 4.5 solution but I haven't found a way to manipulate `HttpResponse.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect` property from my method which returns an `ActionResult`.
However I found the following among the haack comments: it's pretty usable with a little addition: https://gist.github.com/1264267 
If you include this code snippet, I will be happy to accept your answer. Thank you again.

Comment: Or do you know where could I set `HttpResponse.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect`?

Comment: @user2270404 its just `Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true` if you are targeting .net 4.5

Comment: Thank you. However `SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect` seems not to work (at least for AJAX) for me, so I'll stick with the `Application_EndRequest()`