# HttpStatusCodeResult(401) returns “200 OK”

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http-status-codes, asp.net-mvc-5

Using ASP.NET MVC 5, I would like to return appropriate HTTP status code for different scenarios (401 for user is not authenticated, 403 when user has no right for some resource, etc.), then handle them in jQuery.

But the problem is, when I try to return 401, it always returns "200: OK". MVC 5 RC1 was giving "302: Found" instead of 401, so I could use a workaround ([HttpStatusCodeResult(401) returns "302 Found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728631/httpstatuscoderesult401-returns-302-found)).
But now I moved from MVC 5 RC1 to MVC 5 and this behaviour changed. Now it is always "200: OK". So my workaround is useless, of course I can't replace 200 with anything else.

```
public ActionResult My()
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(401, "User is not authenticated."); 
            // Returns "200: OK"
    }

   // ... other code ...
}
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Show us some example code where you employ the 401 so we can help you. No code == no help.

Comment: Code is in my previous question which I have linked. But now I will paste it here as well as per your request.

Comment: You shouldn't be checking `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` explicitly. Authentication in ASP.NET MVC is usually done with attributes; you should apply the Authorize attribute to your method.

Comment: How do you know that it returns 200? Are you using fiddler or anything similar? I created a new MVC 5 project in VS2013 on my machine, pasted `return new HttpStatusCodeResult(401, "User is not authenticated.");` in an action and I'm seeing 302 in fiddler, as I'd expect to see. Do you have different results?

Comment: I had 302 in MVC 5 RC1. In MVC 5 I have 200. I use Firefox web developer console.

Comment: 302 here in MVC 5 release. You have something else you are not telling us about. I recommend starting with a empty MVC 5 project and confirm that it gets 302, not 200. Then find the difference between your project and the new one.

Comment: Also if you are replying to someone here use @user2270404 notation so that the person could get a notification of your reply.

Comment: I too have the same issue and didn't find any solution. I return new HttpUnauthorizedResult(); from the HandleUnauthorizedRequest method and on browser fiddler it receives it as 200 OK. I know this was working for me last week, I did full windows 7 update this week and this stopped working for me.

Comment: What OWIN middleware are you using, if any? It's very common for authentication middleware to intercept a 401 and re-write the response to a challenge. I suspect this kind of re-write to be the root cause of your problem.

Answer (score 5):

The MVC 5+ Pipeline modifies 401 response codes.

**Option 1 With .net 4.5**

you can set     `HttpContext.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect` to true.

e.g. in your custom AuthoriseAttribute.cs

```
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
            {
                Data = "_Logon_",
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized; 
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
        }
```

**Option 2. If not using .net 4.5**

```
  public class SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirectModule : IHttpModule
{
    private static readonly object SuppressAuthenticationKey = new object();

    public static void Register()
    {
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(
            typeof(SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirectModule));
    }

    public static void SuppressAuthenticationRedirect(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Items[SuppressAuthenticationKey] = true;
    }

    public static void SuppressAuthenticationRedirect(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        context.Items[SuppressAuthenticationKey] = true;
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PostReleaseRequestState += OnPostReleaseRequestState;
        context.EndRequest += OnEndRequest;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    private void OnPostReleaseRequestState(object source, EventArgs args)
    {
        var context = (HttpApplication)source;
        var response = context.Response;
        var request = context.Request;

        if (response.StatusCode == 401 && request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
        {
            SuppressAuthenticationRedirect(context.Context);
        }
    }

    private void OnEndRequest(object source, EventArgs args)
    {
        var context = (HttpApplication)source;
        var response = context.Response;

        if (context.Context.Items.Contains(SuppressAuthenticationKey))
        {
            response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            response.ClearContent();
            response.StatusCode = 401;
            response.RedirectLocation = null;
        }
    }
}
```

and in web.config

```
 <modules>
  <add name="SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirectModule" type="SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirectModule"/>
</modules>
```

[See here for more info](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx/)

Answer (score 3):

Solution to the issue can be found in http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.in/2013/12/returning-401-http-status-code-on.html

You need to modify your `Startup` class like this:

```
public partial class Startup
{
private static bool IsAjaxRequest(IOwinRequest request)
{
    IReadableStringCollection query = request.Query;
    if ((query != null) && (query["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    IHeaderDictionary headers = request.Headers;
    return ((headers != null) && (headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest"));
}

// For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnApplyRedirect = ctx =>
            {
                if (!IsAjaxRequest(ctx.Request))
                {
                    ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

}
```

}

Comment: Link doesn't work anymore. The website is still there but the posts are unaccesible

Answer (score 1):

I use simuler code that return 404. Your code could be:

```
public ActionResult My()
{
  if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
  {
    return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
  }
  // ... other code ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Statup.cs I had to set `AutomaticChallenge` to `false`.  Once I did that it stopped doing the URL redirect (which resulted in 200 status) and gave me the 401 status I desired.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
    {
       options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticChallenge = false;  //<@@@@@@@
       //...
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext, int>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
}
```

If you have set some cookie middleware:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
{
   app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()

    {
        AuthenticationScheme = "__auth__",
        LoginPath = "/account/login",
        AccessDeniedPath = "/account/forbidden",
        AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
        AutomaticChallenge = false  //<@@@@@@@
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Identity middleware, redirect can be disabled by removing in LoginPath option in Startup.Auth.cs:

```
   public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ...
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"), // Remove this line
        });
```